# How to encrypt data with a pfx file

Tags: java, encryption, pem, pfx

I have pfx file and I need to encrypt a data by using it and Java. 
First I converted it to a .pem file.

But still I do not know what to do with both now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PFX file is a PKCS#12 file. You can load PKCS#12 key/certificate stores using the `KeyStore` (and "algorithm" string `"PKCS12"`) functionality in Java, after which you can retrieve the contents of the `KeyStore` and use the keys / certificates.

It is better to keep the PFX key store to binary BER / P12 rather than PEM to be compatible with Java. There is a PEM decoder in the Bouncy Castle API, but using the binary file directly should be preferred.